# How to print the 'key' of a dictionary without using loop or any keyword?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

We can simply print the 'value' of a particular key in a dictionary. In the same way how can we print the 'key'?

For instance:

```
favorite_languages = {
 'jen': 'python',
 'sarah': 'c',
 'edward': 'ruby',
 'phil': 'python',
 }
```

We can easily print the values of their respective keys. Can't we print the keys separately?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by add an example of printing such key to your question.

Comment: favorite_languages().keys() will give you all keys, favorite_languages.values() will give you all values, and favorite_languages.items() will return both key and value pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method keys() to extract he keys:

```
favorite_languages.keys()
['sarah', 'edward', 'jen', 'phil']
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't print the keys alone for an instance without iterating.
For value, we will know the key so by using a key we can easily locate a value but in the case of the key, we will not know how to locate the keys. Hence we need to iterate through keys with dictionary name(which contains starting address of the keys in the memory location).

Python also provides inbuild method to list all the keys i.e *'.keys()'*

In your case it will be **favorite_languages.keys()**,

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was looking for this answer

Comment: anytime buddy:)